# Unable to search Microsoft Graph Api V1.0 users using Wildcard search pattern

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am  trying to search users based on wild card regex match using below code snippet:

```
var users = await graphServiceClient.Users.Request().Select(e => new {
    e.DisplayName,
    e.GivenName,
    e.PostalCode
}).Filter(RegexMatch(DisplayName("Rob.* Thomas")
).GetAsync();
```

So, above should match user "Robert Thomas"and RegexMatch is currently not available in filter keyword list ,i have just used as an example to achieve this task.
Below should match Robin Thomas:-
Filter(RegexMatch(DisplayName("Robi.? Thomas") and also in case of UserPrincipalName search and id search etc.

I want to achieve some similar results ,but unable to find any regex search in MS Graph V1.0 documentation.

Please Help me with regex match using MS Graph API V1.0

Comment: Hey have you tried this out currently no wildcard support in graph operation. It would be your work around. Thanks and let me know your update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Microsoft Graph` V1.0 currently doesn't support wildcard like `*` or
>   `%like%` though there is [`$search`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#search-parameter) option which Currently
>   supported only on `messages` and `person` collections.

***`Work Around`:***

You could try bellow way

```
         var users = await graphServiceClient.Users
        .Request()
        .Filter("startswith(displayName,'Rob') and startswith(UserPrincipalName ,'Thomas')")
        .Select( e => new {
                 e.DisplayName,
                 e.GivenName,
                 e.PostalCode
                 })
        .GetAsync();
```

***`Note:`*** *You can bind multiple `and`, `or` clause to execute your custom search.*

Hope it would help.

Comment: Thanks, is there anything like "Equals" similar to startswith

Comment: Glad to help you.