# Cannot fetch users present in Azure AD from Microsoft graph API

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I have made a MVC application and I'm trying to add users to application.

The validation of user needs to be done through Azure AD for which Graph API is used.

Internal users presented in Azure AD are added successfully.

External users are also presented in Azure AD but I get the error

> User not present in AD

I have tried applying all filters but still getting the same issue.

Code used:

```
var authProvider = await GetAuthProvider();
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var user = await graphClient.Users[email].Request().GetAsync();
return true;
```

where email is the string of email passed from application. The code works fine for internal users but not for external users.

Comment: You can use the `filter` attribute to do that, in that case you can write the code this way,`.Filter("startswith(displayName,'Name you want to search') and startswith(UserPrincipalName ,'Name you want to search')").` You could check this [official document for details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp%2Chttp#example-5-use-filter-to-get-all-users-with-a-mail-that-ends-with-acontosocom-including-a-count-of-returned-objects-with-the-results-ordered-by-userprincipalname)

Comment: Another [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60457231/unable-to-search-microsoft-graph-api-v1-0-users-using-wildcard-search-pattern)

Comment: You can also try this pattern `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=userPrincipalName eq 'YourUserPrincipleName'`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `mail` property but you should use `userPrincipalName`

`mail` has form like this

```
AdeleVance@adatum.com
```

but `userPrincipalName` for **external** user has different form

```
AdeleVance_adatum.com#EXT#@contoso.com
AdeleVance_adatum.com#EXT#@contoso.onmicrosoft.com
```

To query a external user using the `userPrincipalName`, encode the hash (#) character. Replace the # symbol with %23.

```
AdeleVance_adatum.com%23EXT%23@contoso.com
```

But `graphClient` should encode the hash character automatically.

Resources:

[Get a user: HTTP request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request)